# How to successfully use ffmpeg to convert images into videos

Tags: ffmpeg

Currently I'm trying to make 5 second videos for each image and then combining them using concat, but I'm having a lot of issues doing this.

Here is my code:

ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 000.jpg -t 5 000.mp4
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 001.jpg -t 5 001.mp4
ffmpeg -f concat -i inputs.txt -codec copy output.mp4

inputs.txt lists the following
file '000.mp4'
file '001.mp4'

Now when I try all of this, I run the output mp4 file and the first part of it works fine, but then once it starts displaying the 001 part of the video, it switches to a gray screen. It doesn't even do that in the stand-alone file 001.mp4.

Any suggestions on what's going on or what I could do fix this?

I've tried so many other things too. Like switching all the files over to png instead, which gave the same issue. I also tried using different output file types like wmv, avi, etc. I'm still very new though so I don't know what else to try.

This is what shows up in my command prompt after running the command.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\images>ffmpeg -f concat -i inputs.txt -codec copy output.mp4
ffmpeg version N-50911-g9efcfbe Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar 13 2013 21:26:48 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libg
sm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libo
pencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-li
bschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-lib
twolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enabl
e-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 19.100 / 52. 19.100
  libavcodec     55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavformat    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavdevice    54.  4.100 / 54.  4.100
  libavfilter     3. 45.103 /  3. 45.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[concat @ 003b9660] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, concat, from 'inputs.txt':
  Duration: 00:00:00.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 28 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444
p, 800x600 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 28 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.0.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv444p, 800x600 [SAR 1:1
 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 28 kb/s, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  250 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      31kB time=00:00:09.88 bitrate=  26.1kbits
/s
video:28kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 13.534948%

C:\xampp\htdocs\images>
```

Comment: Are you having all the images at a time ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your console output shows that you are writing 4:4:4 H.264 output, which very few players support.  (Newer versions of FFmpeg warn about that.)  Add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` before the output file to convert to the widely supported 4:2:0 pixel format.  You could additionally include `-profile:v baseline` to make it work on even more players.  (These options apply to encoding, so don't use them on the command that specifies `-codec copy`.)  You could also try playing your output file with `ffplay`, which is one of the few players that support 4:4:4 H.264 in mp4 files.

If you want the same duration for each image and they are consecutively numbered, you only need a single command such as:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 0.2 -i %3d.jpg -vf fps=10 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

The `-framerate 0.2` sets the input frame rate to 0.2 frames per second (1 frame every 5 seconds).  `%3d` is replaced by 3 digits `000`, `001`, etc. for each frame.  `-vf fps=10` will change the frame rate to 10 frames per second, in this case by duplicating input frames; it is not strictly necessary but can be helpful with low frame rates to make seeking smoother and ensure the full duration for the first and last images, and should not increase the output size by much since frames that are identical to the previous frame can be encoded in a small size.

If you want to continue using the `concat` demuxer, or want different file names or durations for each image, you can specify the image directly with a duration for each one in your `inputs.txt`.  There is no need to create a separate movie file for each image.  For example:

```
file 000.jpg
duration 5
file 001.jpg
duration 5
...
```

Then use the concat demuxer to concatenate them and perform the encoding at the same time:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i inputs.txt -vf fps=10 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

If any of these things don't work, upgrade your FFmpeg to the latest version.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answers. Unfortunately I'm still having an issue though. I tried running "ffmpeg -f concat -i inputs.txt -vf fps=10 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4" with the inputs file structured just like you listed (excluding the dots). Strangely enough, the output is now showing the image that was previously grayed out. But now the first image is nowhere to be seen. I'll try the upgrading to the latest version and get back to you if it's still not working. I thought it was already the latest version, but I will double check.

Comment: Apparently the version I'm using is N-50911-g9efcfbe. It's a bit confusing considering their website is formatted as decimals, with the last one being 2.1 I think. Although I didn't exactly install ffmpeg. I installed imagemagick which apparently comes with it. Also I suppose it doesn't help that I'm using Windows Vista and using xampp.

Comment: Still not having any luck :( I uninstalled imagemagick and then went and installed the latest Zeranoe FFmpeg Build Version "git-9c978f2", but it's still not working. At a loss for words :( Been searching everywheres for the last 48 hours to try and get this sorted out. Trying everything I can find. The only thing I could get working was merging two videos, but they were the default wmv videos in "My Videos" that show up on every windows computer. Creating the videos from images and trying to merge them does not work.

Comment: You are just not seeing the first image?  Have you tried duplicating the first image in `inputs.txt`?

Comment: it was doing that, but then I uninstalled imagemagick and installed the latest Zeranoe FFmpeg Build Version. Now it just seems to be generating a 0 second video that quickly flashes the second image. I'll try duplicate the images a bunch of times to see if there are any differences. EDIT: Wow, actually you're right. Some progress is being made after I duplicate images in the inputs.txt file. :) I'm going to tinker around with this for a while to see if I can find the right amount of times to use it.

Comment: You did it @mark4o - by duplicating the first image once in the inputs.txt file, it's now successfully playing both images for 5 seconds each without any type of gray screen. I don't understand why I had to do this :P But regardless, thank you for the help. I would have been stuck on this forever!

Comment: I'm also trying to do this but it doesn't work for me. It displays only the 1st picture. If I duplicate the first one, it will display it for twice the duration I set.